# Solution for adding around 60V dc-offset on digital signal(0 and 5v) of 10MHz frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, dc-offset

I thought of using Opamp adder for this but the problem is high offset value which can saturate the Opamp. Can you please suggest some other solution ?

Comment: Whats wrong with the standard bias tee like construction for these things?

Comment: Please better describe your application for this problem. As mentioned, a bias tee for the 60VDC and capacitive coupling of the signal is probably a reasonable solution.

Comment: I have to provide this output voltage to CAN_H and CAN_L terminal of Controller Area Network (CAN) where the load resistance is approximately 60 ohm.

Answer (score 3):

You did not give us a lot of details, so I don't know whether my solution is really applicable in your case, but the simplest is to AC-couple your 10MHz digital signal using a capacitor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft4sGam.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the output, you end up with a signal that moves between about 59.5 and 64.5V (due to the diode drop). The diode is here to maintain the capacitor charged to 60V (when the input is at low level). It charges very quickly, and, once charged, the output will move in the same way as the input, because the voltage across the capacitor changes very slowly compared to the input voltage (so when the input changes, the output changes also). You could put a resistor instead (a few kOhm), but this would lead to the output voltage *average* being centered around 60V instead, (so the voltage levels would actually depend on the duty cycle). With the diode, we have the low level fixed at 60V (minus the diode drop).

Note that the input signal must keep changing all the time. If it stays high for too long, you'll end up with a low level on the output after some time (a few ms, with the circuit shown). Because the capacitor will have discharged too much.

Also, be careful about the voltage rating of the capacitor. It must be at least 60V.

***Edit***: I've added (see comments below) a decoupling cap at the diode's anode. This ensures that the short current pulses required to recharge the capacitor when the input goes low can be provided fast enough, and avoid some additional voltage drop due to the resistance of the wire between the supply and the circuit (in case the supply is located far away).

Comment: Can you please explain the importance of diode? As far as i get, it helps to protect the circuit from high negative voltage.

Comment: You're right, I could have explained why it works in more details. I made the edit in my post, you can have a look. Note that the diode is *not* used as a protection, here.

Comment: An inductor may be helpful as well, depending on the impedance of the power supply at 10MHz (may not be that large).

Comment: @OleksandrR. You mean, between the diode anode and the supply ? Eventually, but in this case, you need to say you also put a decoupling capacitor between ground and the diode anode. The inductor without the cap would have bad effects (and actually, the cap alone would be enough, I think).

Comment: Yes, you're right of course; there are various ways to do it depending on whether it is a bias voltage or current that is sought. I just meant that one may find that a 60V dc source by itself may behave rather poorly at 10MHz.

Comment: I think it's worth adding the decoupling capacitor to the answer.

Comment: When i am connecting a load of 50 ohm, the circuit is not working correctly i.e. not giving the level shifted digital voltage( actually giving a constant voltage). I think it is because of the time constant during discharging (R*C) which is very low, so capacitor C1 discharges quickly.

Comment: Can someone please address the problem doing loading the circuit with 50 ohm?

Comment: @NeerajKumar Sorry, I didn't see your request. Your analysis if correct. You can try to use a bigger cap for C1 (1µ, or even 10µ). 50 Ohm is really low, though.

Comment: @dim I thought of using higher capacitance value, but there is a problem of charging this higher capacitance value by large amount consequently larger instantaneous cu.rrent that may destroy the device. I simulated all these things

Comment: @NeerajKumar Which device may be destroyed by the higher current ? The input ? If it can't provide enough current, buffer it. The diode ? The supply ? They should both be able to handle this.

Comment: @dim sorry for late response !! i am talking about diode that may get destroyed by very high current. I simulated the circuit and the amount of current was in kilo amperes for one instant.

Comment: @NeerajKumar Kiloamps??? For real or in simulation? If it's just in simulation, I don't think you need to worry. It won't be the case in reality (due to the non-null resistance of wires), and it is for a very short time anyway. If it's for real, well, you can always put a small resistor (a few ohms) in series with it.

Comment: @dim it was in simulation. Now, i think this will not be the case in real. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. Well, now, if it was useful, you can eventually accept the answer...